# Apache Pulsar Admin UI Login Issue - M1 Mac - Docker-Desktop

Tags: apple-m1, docker-desktop, apache-pulsar

I am having an issue logging into the Pulsar Manager UI running on my k8s cluster in docker-desktop on my M1 Mac.

When I try to login, I am unable to progress past the login page with the default pulsar admin credentials and when I inspect the page I see  the following:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I think the issue has something to do with me being unable to connect with the backed service over port 7750 but I am honestly not sure how I can resolve that. I have deployed using the helm chart and used the minikube.yaml file values to keep replica counts and such down since it's running on the single docker-destop node.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or know of a solution?
If this issue has already come up here, I would love a link to that thread!

Below I have included some details of what's running in my cluster, the other values are all the same as what's included in the helm chart.

Services:

```
k get svc -n pulsar
NAME                         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                               AGE
pulsar-mini-bookie           ClusterIP      None             <none>        3181/TCP,8000/TCP                     21h
pulsar-mini-broker           ClusterIP      None             <none>        8080/TCP,6650/TCP                     21h
pulsar-mini-proxy            LoadBalancer   10.102.192.239   localhost     80:30132/TCP,6650:30925/TCP           21h
pulsar-mini-pulsar-manager   LoadBalancer   10.98.70.14      localhost     9527:30322/TCP                        21h
pulsar-mini-toolset          ClusterIP      None             <none>        <none>                                21h
pulsar-mini-zookeeper        ClusterIP      None             <none>        8000/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP,2181/TCP   21h
```

Output of csrf command, showing that connection is refused from 7750, even if I try to use kubectl port-forward of the pulsar-mini-pulsar-manager pod (though perhaps this isn't the correct way to do it):

```
% CSRF_TOKEN=$(curl http://localhost:7750/pulsar-manager/csrf-token)
curl \
    -H "X-XSRF-TOKEN: $CSRF_TOKEN" \
    -H "Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=$CSRF_TOKEN;" \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -X PUT http://localhost:7750/pulsar-manager/users/superuser \
    -d '{"name": "admin", "password": "apachepulsar", "description": "test", "email": "username@test.org"}'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 7750: Connection refused
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 7750: Connection refused
```

When I run the bin/pulsar-admin commands from my local machine, things work just fine. I simply can't access the commands or the UI for some reason.
Output of some commands below:

```
$ bin/pulsar-admin topics list-partitioned-topics apache/pulsar
"persistent://apache/pulsar/test-topic"
/apache-pulsar-2.9.1
$ bin/pulsar-admin namespaces list apache
"apache/pulsar"
"apache/tester"
$ bin/pulsar-admin topics create-partitioned-topic apache/pulsar/test-topic-2 -p 4
$ bin/pulsar-admin topics list-partitioned-topics apache/pulsar
"persistent://apache/pulsar/test-topic"
"persistent://apache/pulsar/test-topic-2"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the correct port?  What is in your PM configuration?   Anything in the logs?

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/

9527:30322/TCP

https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/administration-pulsar-manager/

in docker we have to specify the second port.

docker run -it 
-p 9527:9527 -p 7750:7750 
-e SPRING_CONFIGURATION_FILE=/pulsar-manager/pulsar-manager/application.properties 
apachepulsar/pulsar-manager:v0.2.0

You only have the 9527 port specific